# How to list internship (I had to take for my bachelors degree) on CV

Tags: resume, internship, germany, student

I was required to take on an internship in a company related to my studies for completing my bachelors degree. It took 6 months and during this period, I was working on a project in the company which later was the topic of my bachelor thesis (also written during this 6 months period).

How should I list this internship in my CV for future applications? (as an internship? as "writing my bachelor thesis"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it was an internship or thesis shouldn't exactly matter for the CV.

**What matters to the employers is what interesting skills have you developed** during that time which they are going to want out of you.

List it as a student intern, but then **go on about what you personally gained from it and can take with you to your employer**:

> ### `Thingy` Developer/Researcher - Student Intern from d/m/y to d/m6/y
>
> - Developed `applied thingamajigs` pertaining the `x engineering` project  for 6 months
> - Worked/Communicated with a team to deliver results on time
> - Introduced/Executed `w,y,z` concepts which brought `good`, improved `workflow`
> - Reported directly to project coordinator through `frequency` meetings
> - Tasked with writing and documenting procedures for writing own bachelor's thesis and report.

Where you want to work also matters when writing this, as some skills may be more attractive than others depending on the position.

Answer (score 2):

> *I was required to take on an internship [...]. How should I list this internship in my CV [...]*

If you were an intern, list it as internship period.

To add:

- You joined a company for internship
- They assigned you a work which you felt interesting and later became the subject of your thesis.
- You completed the internship, with the thesis.

So, you were an intern, the whole time.

Comment: Alright yes, stupid question, obvious answer I guess. But my concerns are the following. I was not working there in an environment I'd consider an internship in that way. I was working full time on my bachelor thesis, which just so happened to require me to take on a project I can write it about in a company. Shouldn't that be treated differently?

Comment: @Suimon You have put effort into this project and gained work experience relevant to your field. I don't see why it should be treated differently. Put it on your CV as an internship and don't worry about it.

Comment: @EgorTamarin But then I think it would be good to atleast mark it as part of my studies instead of "just a regular internship", or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Suimon It's not particularly important what you feel about it. The important part is what is mentioned in the document.

Comment: @Suimon An internship is a learning process in and of itself. If your concern is that the internship will be seen as professional work instead of study, that won't happen since employers have a very good understanding what an internship entails. I have myself completed one internship during my studies (and doing one now) and never have seen my peers make this distinction or employers care about this clarification. Maybe you're reading too hard into this :)